# Can Drupal be used to make any kind of website?

Tags: drupal

I have worked on websites before and always hand coded in each. But as the size of the website grew, it really became difficult to manage them. Our is a college fest website which has a number of online games (like online trading, woodstock , forex and several online quizzes ) . This year we are thinking of migrating to Drupal for this website. Would it be a good choice ?

Comment: What are these games built in/on? Flash?

Comment: jpstrikesback asks a good question.  Flash games aren't a blocker to implementing Drupal, but they do require configuration choice in Drupal regarding download privileges and URL structures for returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal will do a fine job of managing users and associated information about users.  It will create a framework that you can leverage to integrate your games into the system.

However, the games themselves will likely need to be translated into using the Drupal API, which isn't trivial.  Drupal's learning curve can be steep, particularly if you have your own style of doing things.

Having said that, Drupal is extremely flexible and is more aptly called a Web Framework than a Content Management System.

I suggest you create a test version of your site on a local install and see how it feels to try and integrate one of your existing games into the Drupal framework.  You'll know quickly if you like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is flexible enough to be used for any kind of website, but it's primary focus is around content-centric social networking or community sites. It works great for content pages, blog posts, products, etc. If you are building more of an "application" (ie, a web email client, web-based games, etc),you will have more work to do, to work to customize it.